# Multiple Activities in Android using MVVMCross?

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm working on an Xamarin Android app using MVVMCross and have (only for android) multiple screens/activities I want to start from.

I tried to duplicate the SplashScreen, but then none of the Activities boot anymore.

Any suggestions how to get multiple Activities with MainLauncher=true workable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a AppStart.cs to your core project and add this function:

```
public async void Start(object hint = null)
        {
            if (CheckSomething == true)
                ShowViewModel<ViewModels.FirstViewModel>();
            else
                ShowViewModel<ViewModels.SecondViewModel>();
        }
```

Then in your App.cs do:

```
public override void Initialize()
        {
            RegisterAppStart(new AppStart());
        }
```

Comment: tried some things but can't figure out what you meant! AppStart.Start() wont get hit for some reason.

Comment: If you already have a core project, and MvvmCross installed, then you might need to add a "using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;"

Comment: AppStart() works works when only having 1 MvxSplashScreenActivity. My goal is to have more app entry points (app icons)... so how can I fix that?
PS: found your solution also at http://bit.ly/15KA9TC